# And-ing non empty things to an api url using jQuery

Tags: jquery, api

Hello I am calling an api and the api is a simple one that all I need to do is to add some arguments to the url and it returns a json file for me.

I have 3 input fields that have the id's 
generalSearch, dateRange, ageRange.

I wrote some jquery to control the url of the api below:

```
var query = "https://api.myurl.com/search="   
var generalSearch = "x"
var dateRange = "y"
var ageRange = "z"

jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: query + generalSearch + dateRange + ageRange",
        success: function(data)
        {
 }
```

The issue that I am having is that the api I am using needs to have a `+AND+` seperating the arguments for it to work. For example:

`url: query + "+AND+" + generalSearch "+AND+" + dateRange "+AND+" + ageRange"`

which returns:

`https://api.myurl.com/search=x+AND+y+AND+z`

The reason I didnt do this originally in the jQuery is because If one of the arguments is empty it will keep the `+AND+` and break the url. For example if "generalSearch" doesnt have a value the new url will be:

`https://api.myurl.com/search=+AND+y+AND+z`

So I am looking for a solution with the logic: `If a field has a value, add the value of the field and add +AND+ to the end of it but If it does not exist then dont add either one.`

Any suggestions?

Sorry if this question wasnt explained properly I tried my best

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can write turnary operators here to identify weather your parameter is null or not and according to that you can send value in your ajax call please look at the snippet below
eg.

```js
var query = "https://api.myurl.com/search="   
var arg1="x" //it can be null as well
var generalSearch = arg1? arg1 + "+AND+" : "";
console.log(generalSearch);
var arg2="";
var dateRange = arg2? arg2 +"+AND+" : "";
console.log(dateRange );
var ageRange = "z"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but what happens if ageRange is null and date range isnt? the url will have a +AND+ at the end of the url right? that will still break it

Comment: Yes it will break in that case.

Comment: aw dangit. is there any way to search for the last instance of +AND+ and remove it from the url then?

Comment: Hi, In that case you can try below turnary operation.
`var arg2="c";
var ageRange =""//it's null here
var dateRange = arg2 && ageRange ? arg2 +"+AND+" : arg2? arg2 : ""
console.log(dateRange );`